# error in typescript for each loop syntax

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a class with typescript 2.0.3 but I have some problems and I don't know why.

this is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 
import {Car} from '../interfaces/car';

class PrimeCar implements Car 
{
  constructor(public vin, public year, public brand, public color) {}
}
@Component({
  selector: 'rb-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  displayDialog: boolean;
  car: Car = new PrimeCar(null, null, null , null);
  selectedCar: Car;
  newCar: boolean;
  cars: Car[];
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
this.cars = [ {vin: '111', year: '5554' , brand: '5646' , color: '6466' },
              {vin: '111', year: '5554' , brand: '5646' , color: '6466' },
              {vin: '111', year: '5554' , brand: '5646' , color: '6466' },
              {vin: '111', year: '5554' , brand: '5646' , color: '6466' }
             ];
  }    
  showDialogToAdd() {
    this.newCar = true;
    this.car = new PrimeCar(null, null, null, null);
    this.displayDialog = true;
  }
  save() {
    const cars = [...this.cars];
    if (this.newCar) {
      cars.push(this.car);
    } else {
      cars[this.findSelectedCarIndex()] = this.car;
    }
    this.cars = cars;
    this.car = null;
    this.displayDialog = false;
  }
  delete() {
    const index = this.findSelectedCarIndex();
    this.cars = this.cars.filter((val, i) => i !== index);
    this.car = null;
    this.displayDialog = false;
  }
  onRowSelect(event) {
    this.newCar = false;
    this.car = this.cloneCar(event.data);
    this.displayDialog = true;
  }    
  cloneCar(c: Car): Car {
    const car = new PrimeCar(null, null, null, null);
    for (let  prop: string in c) {
      car[prop] = c[prop];
    }
    return car;
  }
  findSelectedCarIndex(): number {
    return this.cars.indexOf(this.selectedCar);
  }
}
```

In the cloneCar method, I have this error when trying to write:

```
for (let  prop: string in c) {
...}
```

> Tslint: identifier 'prop' is never reassigned ,use const instead of
>   let

this is an image capture from my IDE:
[see error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/254AK.png)

NB: I'm using this code in angular project version 2.3.0

Some help, please!

Comment: it's just a linting error, it's telling you to use const instead of let in that for because you are never reassining prop to another value.

Comment: still given problem , is that problem caused by the wrong version of typescript ?

Comment: no, it's a style indication tslint gives you.. https://palantir.github.io/tslint/

Comment: It is good to follow this rule. It makes code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: yes i do , i 'm still searching for solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your IDE is right. You are declaring `prop` with `let` and not with `const`.

`let` is for variables that are subject to change. For example:

```
let x = 5;
x = 7;
```

We declared `x` and then we changed it's value.

`const` is for values that won't change. For example:

```
const x = 5;
x = 7; // Throws an error.
```

So, in your case, as `prop` doesn't and won't change, has to be a constant (`const`):

```
for (const  prop: string in c) {
...}
```

Check [this documentation](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#let--const) for a deeper understanding.

Comment: Note that IDE and compilers are rarely wrong... With the exception of XCode :D

Comment: @n00dl3 hahaha! Yeah! Also you can decide what to show as error or not. So depends also on how you configured your IDE. Anyhow, are always a great help to produce a better code. IDE's corrections helped me a lot tbh... :D

Answer (score 0):

variable prop is only used to read. you do not assign anything to it so it doesn't change. this means it should be const not let.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all it is just linting error telling you that it is better to use `const` instead of `let` if you are not reassigning variable.

2nd is that I would go with [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) instead which does the same but is one-liner.

Comment: An even cleaner approach than `Object.assign` would be to use `{...}`.